# iOS Notes - I shared a note and can't see other person edits, while he can see mine

Tags: ios, icloud, sharing, notes.app

iPad 2018, iOS 12.1.4 - I created a note in the cloud (Notes are On in the iCloud settings, the note is certainly not in "on my phone" category) - share (the person icon, not the share icon) - copy link - enter iCloud email of my friend from contacts - press Copy link - paste link to a messenger. 
He opens the link on his iPhone XS, iOS 12.1.4 and appears in the shared list with a color assigned. He edits then, I select "highlight changes" - and everything is highlighted in my color only. I see no changes.Then I add a line and he sees that. Then he removes that line and I don't see that. We both have a little person icon next to the note in the notes list, and a checkmark on the person icon inside the note.

Tried restarting app by force closing, rebooting the iPad, opening icloud.com on my PC - no changes there either.

I never shared the notes before. What am I doing wrong? Does anyone has any thoughts?